# Sorting/Filtering from 2 arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have these 2 arrays:

```
var masterArray = [
        {'id' : '1', 'title' : 'Title 1'},
        {'id' : '2', 'title' : 'Title 2'},
        {'id' : '3', 'title' : 'Title 3'},
        {'id' : '4', 'title' : 'Title 4'},
        {'id' : '5', 'title' : 'Title 5'},
        {'id' : '6', 'title' : 'Title 6'},
        {'id' : '7', 'title' : 'Title 7'}
    ];

var sortFilterInfo = [
    {'id' : '6', 'sortOrder' : 1},
    {'id' : '2', 'sortOrder' : 2},
    {'id' : '7', 'sortOrder' : 3}
]
```

With this information I need an array which gives me this sorted filtered array: ( I am only using native DOM Array methods (ES6) (map/filter/sort)      and **NOT** Jquery,lodash, etc.

```
var resultArray = [
    {'id' : '6', 'title' : 'Title 6'},
    {'id' : '2', 'title' : 'Title 2'},
    {'id' : '7', 'title' : 'Title 7'}
]
```

Thanks!

Comment: So not using any external Javascript libraries?

Comment: well that was the point. but as long as it's not jquery I don't mind bringing in another JS util lib

Comment: is the sortFilterInfo a static value or will it be dynamic at some point of time?

Comment: yes it's very dynamic,  changes constantly. masterArray stays the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this work? (**EDIT:** Comment if you want me to explain what it does)

```
// Create arrays
var masterArray = [
    {'id' : '1', 'title' : 'Title 1'},
    {'id' : '2', 'title' : 'Title 2'},
    {'id' : '3', 'title' : 'Title 3'},
    {'id' : '4', 'title' : 'Title 4'},
    {'id' : '5', 'title' : 'Title 5'},
    {'id' : '6', 'title' : 'Title 6'},
    {'id' : '7', 'title' : 'Title 7'}
];

var sortFilterInfo = [
    {'id' : '6', 'sortOrder' : 1},
    {'id' : '2', 'sortOrder' : 2},
    {'id' : '7', 'sortOrder' : 3}
]

var resultArray = new Array();

// Sort arrays
masterArray.sort(function(a, b){return parseInt(a.id)-parseInt(b.id)});
sortFilterInfo.sort(function(a, b){return a.sortOrder-b.sortOrder});

// Push to array the id of the filter...
for (var i in sortFilterInfo) {
    resultArray.push(masterArray[parseInt(sortFilterInfo[i].id)-1]);
}

// console.log(resultArray);
//
// resultArray = [
//     {'id' : '6', 'title' : 'Title 6'},
//     {'id' : '2', 'title' : 'Title 2'},
//     {'id' : '7', 'title' : 'Title 7'}
// ]
```

Comment: Thanks! I had fun making this!

Comment: andrew you look like you're 12. little genius : ) thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You just go through the `sortFilterInfo` array and then pluck the items from the master array.

Here is an example:

```
function myFunc(master, sortOrder) {
    var result = [];

    // Sort sortOrder so it is ordered correctly
    // The array is cloned so it does not affect
    // the original array
    var order = sortOrder.concat().sort(function (a, b) {
        return a.sortOrder - b.sortOrder;
    });
    // Function to find an item in the master array
    var find = function (value) {
        var result = -1;
        master.some(function (item, index) {
            if (item.id == value) {
                result = index;
                return true;
            }
        });
        return result;
    };
    // Go through the orderings and pick the items
    // from the master array
    order.forEach(function (item) {
        var index = find(item.id);
        if (index !== -1) {
            result.push(master[index]);
        }
    });
    return result;
}
var result = myFunc(masterArray, sortFilterInfo);
```

Comment: this works great too ! especially when master array id's aren't numbers, but random text.