# Sorting/Filtering on array based on another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I just posted a question here ( [Sorting/Filtering from 2 arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35823006/sorting-filtering-from-2-arrays#35823071) ) but I ran into a problem because my id's could be random strings:

so I have a master array with all the data :

```
var masterArray = [
        {'id' : 'wedfd', 'title' : 'Title 1'},
        {'id' : 'hji', 'title' : 'Title 2'},
        {'id' : 'sdfds', 'title' : 'Title 3'},
        {'id' : 'fgfgf', 'title' : 'Title 4'},
        {'id' : 'kkd', 'title' : 'Title 5'},
        {'id' : 'jjj', 'title' : 'Title 6'},
        {'id' : 'abc', 'title' : 'Title 7'}
    ];
```

I get an array with this info :

```
var sortFilterInfo = [
    {'id' : 'jjj', 'sortOrder' : 1},
    {'id' : 'hji', 'sortOrder' : 2},
    {'id' : 'abc', 'sortOrder' : 3}
]
```

With this information I need an array which gives me this sorted filtered array: ( I am only using native DOM Array methods (ES6) (map/filter/sort) and NOT Jquery,lodash, etc.

```
var resultArray = [
    {'id' : 'jjj', 'title' : 'Title 6', 'sortOrder' : 1},
    {'id' : 'hji', 'title' : 'Title 2', 'sortOrder' : 2},
    {'id' : 'abc', 'title' : 'Title 7', 'sortOrder' : 3}
]
```

Thanks!

Comment: You should post what you've tried as well

Comment: so in the other post the masterArray ids were all integers. so the answer from @Andrew Mast worked great. but now I have id's that are just random strings

Comment: All the solutions posted below seem to be O(n^2) in general or O(n*m). I wonder if there is a better solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** and **[`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)** ( using ES6 arrow notation )

```js
var masterArray = [{
  'id': 'wedfd',
  'title': 'Title 1'
}, {
  'id': 'hji',
  'title': 'Title 2'
}, {
  'id': 'sdfds',
  'title': 'Title 3'
}, {
  'id': 'fgfgf',
  'title': 'Title 4'
}, {
  'id': 'kkd',
  'title': 'Title 5'
}, {
  'id': 'jjj',
  'title': 'Title 6'
}, {
  'id': 'abc',
  'title': 'Title 7'
}];

var sortFilterInfo = [{
  'id': 'jjj',
  'sortOrder': 1
}, {
  'id': 'hji',
  'sortOrder': 2
}, {
  'id': 'abc',
  'sortOrder': 3
}]

// if `sortFilterInfo` is not sorted then sort it using sort()
// sortFilterInfo.sort((a,b) => a.id-b.id)


// iterate over `sortFilterInfo` array for generating sorted array
var res = sortFilterInfo.map(v => {
  // get element from `masterArray` based on the id
  var obj = masterArray.find(v1 => v1.id == v.id);
  // add sortOrder to the object
  obj.sortOrder = v.sortOrder;
  // return updated object
  return obj;
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(res, null, 3) + '</pre>');
```

---

Or the following with an array of `id` and later get the index using **[`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)**

```js
var masterArray = [{
  'id': 'wedfd',
  'title': 'Title 1'
}, {
  'id': 'hji',
  'title': 'Title 2'
}, {
  'id': 'sdfds',
  'title': 'Title 3'
}, {
  'id': 'fgfgf',
  'title': 'Title 4'
}, {
  'id': 'kkd',
  'title': 'Title 5'
}, {
  'id': 'jjj',
  'title': 'Title 6'
}, {
  'id': 'abc',
  'title': 'Title 7'
}];

var sortFilterInfo = [{
  'id': 'jjj',
  'sortOrder': 1
}, {
  'id': 'hji',
  'sortOrder': 2
}, {
  'id': 'abc',
  'sortOrder': 3
}]

// if `sortFilterInfo` is not sorted then sort it using sort()
// sortFilterInfo.sort((a,b) => a.id-b.id)

// create an array with all id
var idArr=masterArray.map(v=>v.id);


// iterate over `sortFilterInfo` array for generating sorted array
var res = sortFilterInfo.map(v => {
  // get element from `masterArray` based on the id
  var obj = masterArray[idArr.indexOf(v.id)];
  // add sortOrder to the object
  obj.sortOrder = v.sortOrder;
  // return updated object
  return obj;
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(res, null, 3) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: @29er : glad to help

Answer (score 1):

Here is a kind of brute force approach. If sortFilterInfo is in order, this solution will always work. Basically just check (lowest to highest order) if it is within the masterArray, if it is, it is guaranteed to be pushed into the correct place of the result array.

```
var masterArray = [
  {'id' : 'wedfd', 'title' : 'Title 1'},
  {'id' : 'hji', 'title' : 'Title 2'},
  {'id' : 'sdfds', 'title' : 'Title 3'},
  {'id' : 'fgfgf', 'title' : 'Title 4'},
  {'id' : 'kkd', 'title' : 'Title 5'},
  {'id' : 'jjj', 'title' : 'Title 6'},
  {'id' : 'abc', 'title' : 'Title 7'}
];

var sortFilterInfo = [
  {'id' : 'jjj', 'sortOrder' : 1},
  {'id' : 'hji', 'sortOrder' : 2},
  {'id' : 'abc', 'sortOrder' : 3}
];

var resultArray = [];

for(var i = 0; i < sortFilterInfo.length; i++) {
  for(var j = 0; j < masterArray.length; j++) {
    if (sortFilterInfo[i].id === masterArray[j].id) {
      resultArray.push({id : masterArray[j].id, title: masterArray[j].title, sortOrder: sortFilterInfo[i].sortOrder});
    }
  }
}
```